# How to write Bazel rules that work with external repositories?

Tags: bazel

The Bazel Starlark API does strange things with files in external repositories. I have the following Starlark snippet:

```
    print(ctx.genfiles_dir)
    print(ctx.genfiles_dir.path)
    print(output_filename)
    ret = ctx.new_file(ctx.genfiles_dir, output_filename)
    print(ret.path)
```

It is creating the following output:

```
DEBUG: build_defs.bzl:292:5: <derived root>
DEBUG: build_defs.bzl:293:5: bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/genfiles
DEBUG: build_defs.bzl:294:5: google/protobuf/descriptor.upb.c
DEBUG: build_defs.bzl:296:5: bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/genfiles/external/com_google_protobuf/google/protobuf/descriptor.upb.c
```

That extra `external/com_google_protobuf` comes seemingly out of nowhere, and it makes my rule fail:

- I tell protoc to generate into `ctx.genfiles_dir.path` (which is `bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/genfiles`).
- So protoc generates `bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/genfiles/google/protobuf/descriptor.upb.c`
- Bazel fails because I didn't generate `bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/genfiles/external/com_google_protobuf/google/protobuf/descriptor.upb.c`

Likewise, when I try to call `file.short_path` on a source file from an external repository, I get a result like `../com_google_protobuf/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto`. This seems quite unhelpful, so I just wrote some manual code to strip off the leading `../com_google_protobuf/`.

Am I missing something?  How can I write this rule in a way that doesn't feel like I'm fighting Bazel the whole time?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something?

The basic problem, as you already realized, is that you have two path "namespaces" the one that protoc sees (i.e. import paths) and the one that bazel sees (i.e. the path you pass to `declare_file()`.

2 things to note:

1) All paths declared with `declare_file()` get the path `<bin dir>/<package path incl. workspace>/<path you passed to declare_file()>`

2) All actions are executed from `<bin dir>` (unless [`output_to_genfils=True`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/globals.html#rule) in which case this switches to `<gen dir>` as in your example.

Trying to solve the exact same problem you encountered, I resorted to stripping the known path from the output_file's path to determine which directory to pass as p:

```py
# This code is run from the context of the external protobuf dependency
proto_path = "google/a/b.proto"
output_file = ctx.actions.declare_file(proto_path)

# output_file.path would be `<gen_dir>/external/protobuf/google/a/b.proto`
# Strip the known proto_path from output_file.path
protoc_prefix = output_file.path[:-len(proto_path)]

print(protoc_prefix) # Prints: <gen_dir>/external/protobuf

command = "{protoc} {proto_paths} {cpp_out} {plugin} {plugin_options} {proto_file}".format(
        ...
        cpp_out = "--cpp_out=" + protoc_prefix,
        ...
)
```

#### Alternatives

You may also be able to construct the same path with `ctx.bin_dir`, `ctx.label.workspace_name`, `ctx.label.package`, and `ctx.label.name`.

#### Misc.

`proto_library` recently gained an attribute [`strip_import_prefix`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/protocol-buffer.html#proto_library.strip_import_prefix). When used, the above is not correct, as all dependent files are symlinked into a new directory from which they have the relative paths declared with `strip_import_prefix`.

The path format is:

```
<bin dir>/<repo>/<package>/_virtual_base/<label name>/<path `import`ed in .proto files>
i.e.
<bin dir>/external/protobuf/_virtual_base/b_proto/google/a/b.proto
```

Assuming you are building an external repo called `protobuf`, which contains a `BUILD` file at its root with a target named `b_proto`, which in turn, relies on a `proto_library` wrapping `google/a/b.proto` AND uses the `strip_import_prefix` attribute.

Comment: I discovered the same workaround myself (the `output_file.path[:-len(proto_path)]` thing). But this still seems like I'm fighting Bazel. It still seems wrong that `ctx.new_file(ctx.genfiles_dir, output_filename).path` has `external/com_google_protobuf` in it when neither `ctx.genfiles_dir.path` nor `output_filename` has it. I can't see why this would be useful behavior to anybody. It seems like everyone will have to keep rediscovering these same workarounds.